# Is it possible to have tag suggestion in ctags while searching for a tag?

Tags: ctags

I am using `exuberent-ctags` with `vim 8.0`. While searching for a tag with a long name, I'd like to have a list of suggestions having the typed string as the sub-string when I use the `:ta` command. What I want is to have a feature like Sublime's `Ctrl+P`, that allows you to search for a symbol. Is it possible to achieve the same with `ctags`?

Comment: You can use tab completion on the `:ta` command, but it's not great... It gets a bit better if you `:set wildmenu`, possibly together with `:set wildmode=full`. I think one of the plug-ins (like CtrlP or perhaps fzf) might implement completion for tags that might be much more powerful, maybe check them out.

Answer (score 1):

[You can use](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-D) <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> in command-line mode, it shows you all the suggestions you would get with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion. e.g. `:ta func<C-D>`

Apart from that, fzf plugin have a `:Tags` and CtrlP have `:CtrlPTag` that allows fuzzy-searching for tags. But if you don't use their other features, it might be better to keep it simple with <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> if it works for you.